# Searching for closest data (epoch time) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, search

I'm learning python actually and i'm quite stuck with this.

I've got a df of 10.000 rows, indexed from 0 to 9.999, in first column, this is some epoch time in ms like 1651074378000 which represents hours.

I have a random epoch time which is not equal to any of thoses 10.000 ones. it is between two of them.

I did a loop reading every epoch, and checking if "> i" , and "< i+1", then return i
When i do this on 15.000 df, it takes ages.

If the epoch was equal, it would be way easiest in my opinion.

I'm not sure how to handle this the fastest way, maybe with Numpy but I still can't tell when numpy is faster.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204549/lookup-closest-value-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed way shorter to write and use, but it's not faster, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work.

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(range(100,600,100))
print(dft)

     0
0  100
1  200
2  300
3  400
4  500
```

This then gives the **index** for the greatest value that is less than or equal to the target value:

```
target = 399
(dft[0]<=target)[::-1].idxmax()  

2
```

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed way shorter to write and use, but it's not faster, thanks for the answer :)